# Send monitor / null-sink over network with pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio

This is the scenario:

On my computer (we name it A) my microphone and the output from VLC get mixed into a null-sink / loopback which is used in TeamSpeak. This is how I do this:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual sink_properties=device.description="Mic+Sounds"
pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo sink=Virtual
pactl load-module module-combine-sink slaves="Virtual,alsa_output.pci-0000_02_04.0.analog-stereo"
```

This way the microphone input AND sounds played in VLC are sent simultanous in TeamSpeak. Also I can hear all sounds from VLC and there's no loop / feedback.

I have a second computer (lets call it B) which uses the (physical) microphone source from A. Now I would like to use the **mixed** mic/sound audio from A as input on B. Although the combined mic+sound device is shown on B, it only records silence.

Any Ideas?